# AngularJS submitting handling a form with multiple inner controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Good day pals, I have just started with AngularJS and have been having nightmares!

I have the following partial html form included within a parent html using ng-view.

```
 <form name="FormName" ng-submit="addToBasket()" ng-controller="UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl">

        <input type="hidden" name="fieldA" ng-model="fieldA" " value="{{fieldA}}">

        <div  ng-controller="ControllerA">       
            <input type="text" name="fieldB" ng-model="fieldB" typeahead="stop for stop in stopList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"> 
        </div> 

         <div ng-controller="ControllerB">      
                  <input type="text"  name="fieldC" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="fieldC" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'22-06-2015'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
         </div> 

         <div ng-controller="ControllerC" >      
                <button type="button" ng-click="populateFieldDDropDown()"> Show Field D  </button> 
                <select id="fieldD"
                        name="fieldD"                
                        ng-model="fieldD"
                        ng-options="fieldD as fieldD for fieldD in fieldDList">
                </select>
        </div>       

        <div ng-controller="ControllerD">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="fieldE" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="fieldE" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'22-06-2015'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
        </div>

        <div>
                <button type="submit"> Add to shopping basket  </button>  
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
app.controller('UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl', ['$scope', 'ShoppingBasketFactory', '$location',
                                  function ($scope, ShoppingBasketFactory, $location) {

    //callback for ng-submit 'createCard':    
    $scope.addToBasket= function () {

        alert('NEW PRODUCT DETAILS = 1 '+$scope.fieldA+" 2 "+$scope.fieldB+" 3 "+$scope.fieldC+" 4 "+$scope.fieldD);

        //JSON Object is composed here 
        var newProductDetailsJSON = {...........};

        ShoppingBasketFactory.create(newProductDetailsJSON,
                function(data) {
                    //Success Handler
                    $scope.success =true;
                    },
                    function(error) {
                    //Error Handler
                    $scope.success =false;
                    }   
        );
    } 
}]);
```

The ControllerA is used to handle the typeahead boostrap angularjs plugin.
The ControllerB is used for the datepicker plugin of boostrap angularjs .
The ControllerC is used to add a pane to the page when user clicks on the button "Show Field D".
The ControllerD is used for the datepicker plugin of boostrap angularjs .
The hidden field fieldA is retrieved from the request when loading the page for the first time.

So, the Controllers A,D,C,D are first invoked as the user completes the ordering form from top to bottom and all the actions work.

The problem is when I submit the whole page by clicking the "Add to shopping basket" submit button, I can only retrieve the hidden field fieldA in my main controller UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl ( I guess this is because its not within a controller). I get undefined variable error for the other fields fieldB,fieldC, fieldD.

I am processing the order form in UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl controller using the $scope.fieldB,$scope.fieldC,$scope.fieldD.

I need to capture all the form fields i.e. all fields within the various nested controllers i.e. A,B,C,D in my main controller and send to a restful webservice as a JSON object.

I honestly thought this would be a no brainer, but there you go again. I come across at least 2 Anularjs Issues per day in my quest to implement a real enterprise rich client with AngularJS.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl` has scope, and all elements that have the `ng-controller` attribute will also have their own scope, and they will be children of `UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl` scope.

```
- scope::UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl
  - scope::ControllerA
  - scope::ControllerB
  - scope::ControllerC
  - scope::ControllerD
```

Because your `ng-model` exists under some child scope, they will always set the model to the nearest scope, which is `Controller[ABCD]`, and not `UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl` as you expecting.

To handle this condition, you will need to set some property on the `UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl` scope, and it need to be `object`.

```
app.controller('UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // This property will be `ng-model` on template.
    $scope.fields = {
        'A': '',
        'B': '',
        'C': '',
        'D': '',
    };
}]);
```

Because the model is now object, you'll have to write your template like this :

```
    <div ng-controller="ControllerD">
        <!-- See the `ng-model` attribute -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="fields.D" />
    </div>
```

By doing this, your child scope `ng-model` will set the value to the nearest scope that has `fields` property, which is `UpdateShoppingBasketCtrl` as you expecting.

http://jsfiddle.net/rxS2Q/

Comment: Hello Igbal, thanks for the response, but I dont understand your explanation. Could you shed some more light please.